# How to create two unions within a struct in C/C++ with IDL?

Tags: struct, union, idl

I have a struct containing two unions and I need to make it rpcable to use with IDL. This is how it looks now:

```
typedef struct _MY_STRUCT
{
    int usingB;
    [switch_is(usingB)] union 
    {
        [default]
            float value1A;
        [case(true)]
            float value1B;
    };
    [switch_is(usingB)] union
    {
        [default]
            float value2A;
        [case(true)]
            float value2B;
    };
} MY_STRUCT;
```

It's throwing undeclared identifier errors, but I don't know the syntax to use. I don't even think this is right, but it's the only thing I could get to work. How do I make this work?